# React Router Declared but doesn't work please

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello I want it to render `InstrumentPage` with no props when `#/` is access but when `#/ipb` is access pass `ipb` as the props entity. But it's not working.

```
  render() {
    return (<React.Fragment>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' render={(props) => <InstrumentPage {...props} />}/>
          {Object.keys(AppConfig).forEach((property) =>
            <Route path={property} render={(props) => <InstrumentPage {...props} entity={property} />} />)
          }
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </React.Fragment>);
  }
```

AppConfig

```
const AppConfig = {
  pb: {
    header: 'PBHeader',
    body: 'PBBody',
  },
  ipb: {
    header: 'IPBHeader',
    body: 'IPBBody',
  },
};    
export default AppConfig;
```

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything, did you mean to `map` over the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `map` and return the `Route`, `forEach` won't return anything but `undefined`.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <InstrumentPage {...props} />}/>
    {Object.keys(AppConfig).map((property) =>
      <Route 
        path={`/${property}`} 
        render={ (props) => <InstrumentPage {...props} entity={property} /> } 
      />
     )
    }
</Switch>
```

**Note:** When you write `path={property}` which means `path={ipb}` or `path={pb}`  which is incorrect path. Correct path should be `path="/ipb"` (Notice the slash), for this you need to do `/${property}` [contains  back-tick] (using [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

Also add `exact` prop for your first `Route` otherwise it will going to match for all the `Routes`.